# Archimedean property by contrapositive

Tags: logic, real-numbers

Archimedean property of $\mathbb{R}$:
$$\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}\text{ with }x>0,\exists n\in \mathbb{N}:nx>y. (*)$$

I saw how this theorem is proved by contradiction.

I would like to see how this theorem will look in the contrapositive form.

**QUESTION 1:** Can I put (*) in the conditional form "*if A, then B*"? My attempt:
$$\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}\text{ with }x>0 \implies \exists n\in \mathbb{N}:nx>y. (**)?$$
Or "*if for any real x and y with x>0 then there is natural n such that nx>y.*"
And the if part looks stangely.

**QUESTION 2:** If I can do that then how  will do look (**) in the contrapositive form "*if not B, then not A*"?

Comment: Advice: when learning to understand the contrapositive, don't use the symbol $\implies$, but rather write the "if" and the "then" explicitly—it helps one parse the assertion and group the correct pieces together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\forall x,y\in\mathbb R$ is just stating the domain of the proposition and can be expressed as:

> Given real numbers $x$ and $y$

Now to the actual inference:

> if $x>0$, then there exists $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $nx>y$

This part has the form:
$$
A\implies B
$$
and the contrapositive is:
$$
\neg B\implies \neg A
$$
which is:

> if $\forall n\in\mathbb N$ we have $nx\leq y$, then $x\leq 0$

Answer (score 2):

> > Archimedean property of $\mathbb{R}$: $$\forall x,y\in
> > \mathbb{R}\text{ with }x>0,\exists n\in \mathbb{N}:nx>y.$$

Here, “with” [means](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4506542/21813) ‘such that’.

> $$\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}\text{ with }x>0 \implies
> \exists n\in \mathbb{N}:nx>y.\tag2$$

Correction: $$\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}\Big(x>0 \implies
\exists n\in \mathbb{N}:nx>y\Big).\tag{2c}$$

Leaving the “with” there is grammatically incorrect:

- ✗ “for each $m$ *with* $m$ is positive *implies that* $m+1$ is positive”

versus

- ✔ “for each $m,\:m$ is positive *implies that* $m+1$ is positive”
- ✔ “for each $m,\:$ *if* $m$ is positive, *then* $m+1$ is positive”

> "if for any real $x$ and $y$ with $x>0$ then there is natural $n$ such that $nx>y.$" And the "if" part looks strange.

Your translation is incoherent; correction:

“For each pair of real $x$ and $y,$ **if** $x>0,$ **then** for some natural $n,\; nx>y.$”

> **QUESTION 2:** If I can do that then how  will do look $(2)$ in the contrapositive form "*if not B, then not A*"?

Regardless of whether a statement P is quantified, its contrapositive is logically equivalent to P itself. So, when taking the contrapositive of $(2),$ just modify the conditional portion, leaving the external quantifiers alone (otherwise the equivalence will be lost).

---

**Addendum**

> Re: the contrapositive, is this correct? $$\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}\Big( \forall n\in \mathbb{N}:nx\leq y \implies x\leq 0\Big).$$

Yes, but notice that the colon is no longer read as "such that", so leaving it there is potentially confusing? The colon (including in $(2\text c)$ above) is [at best](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4412936/21813) superfluous. So, slightly better: $$\forall x{,}y{\in} \mathbb{R}\;\Big( \forall n{\in} \mathbb{N}\;nx\leq y \implies x\leq 0\Big).$$ Also, do note that this is NOT equivalent to $$\forall x{,}y{\in} \mathbb{R}\;\forall n{\in} \mathbb{N}\;\Big(nx\leq y \implies x\leq 0\Big).$$

Comment: Thanks! I understand the first part. But I am not sure about the second part. $\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}\Big(
\forall n\in \mathbb{N}:nx\leq y \implies x\leq 0\Big).$ Is it correct?

Comment: @Mokhmad-SalekhKhekhaev: That is correct.