# "with", "where" or "and"? A question about good writing style.

Tags: functions, article-writing

If I am writing down this function $$ f: D^2\to \mathbb R  $$
and want to communicate that $D\subseteq \mathbb R$, should I write $$ f: D^2\to \mathbb R \quad \mathrm {with} \quad D\subseteq \mathbb R$$ or $$ f: D^2\to \mathbb R \quad \mathrm {where} \quad D\subseteq \mathbb R$$ or $$ f: D^2\to \mathbb R \quad \mathrm {and} \quad D\subseteq \mathbb R$$?

Comment: No big difference for me...

Comment: I prefer either of the first two but that is a personal preference, not a rule of grammar.

Comment: the last one I could perhaps see it in something like..."the theorem is true under the condition that $f:D^2 \to \Bbb R$ and $D\subset \Bbb R$".

Comment: My preference: "Consider the function $f(x)=ax^{bc}$, where $a\in\mathbb Z$ with $a>0$, $b\in\mathbb N$, and $c\in\mathbb Q^+$". "Where" is a first specification, "with" is a further specification of something that's already concrete, and "and" comes at the end of a list.

Comment: 1. Do note that option 2 does require a comma to precede "where". $\quad$ 2. Although I'm partial to options 2 and 3 (1 sounds a teeeeny bit contrived; 2 sounds natural; 3 goes straight to the logical point), all three options are clear/okay. $\quad$ 3. I agree with @Vercassivelaunos's illustration. $\quad$ 4. Two relevant previous answers of mine: [Are "where" and "such that" interchangeable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4506542/21813) and [Ambiguity of "where"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4266064/21813).